# Xcode 11.1 stuck on archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode 11.1 and I'm trying to upload a testFlight 
but it's stuck on the archiving.

the compile of the archiving stuck on specific log all the time 'Touch'
[image: ScreenShot]
I've already tried to set this code in the PodFile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    next unless target.name == '<NAME OF POD>'
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      next unless config.name.start_with?('Release')
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end
  end
end
```

and tried to set `ld_verify_bitcode == NO` in the Build Settings.